# Как создать аналог malloc, free, check, init

Tags: c, алгоритм, память

Есть задание, где стоит реализовать функции malloc, free, check, init. Можно использовать любые функции, кроме вышесказанных.
Вот мои попытки реализации malloc:

```
void *malloc(unsigned int len){
  char *arr;
  for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
    arr[i] = ' ';   
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Я понимаю, что он не верный, но это пока все, что приходит в голову. Уважаемые знатоки, не могли Вы мне дать направления, как это сделать? Любая помощь, ссылка или алгоритм приветствуется.
Есть догадка, чтобы реализовать **free**, нужно пройтись циклом и задать значение NULL. Но это работает на интерпретированных языках (без типизации, таких как Js, PHP...). А вот как на С это сделать правильно?
Изображения задания

Comment: Дергайте системные функции управления память. Тот же malloc - обертка над HeapAlloc в винде, например.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, благодарю за ответ. А есть еще варианты? Я думаю, что преподаватель может забокорить. Но решение не должно быть сложное, это только начало изучения С

Comment: ну тут как раз основной вопрос откуда вы изначально возьмете память которую потом будете выделять. Можно конечно сделать большой глобальный массив и выдавать его кусочки. но это кажется странным решением. но по крайней мере функции уже можно будет реализовать. описк свободного блока, его выдача, перезапись списка свободных блоков и т.п. Можно отразить на память файл с помощью mmap и вот у вас на руках большой кусок памяти (размером с отраженный файл) и можно выдавать из него. Либо получить этот кусок у ОС специфическими вызовами функций ОС

Comment: Простую реализацию функций `malloc` и `free` можно посмотреть в [исходниках FreeRTOS](https://github.com/jameswalmsley/FreeRTOS/blob/master/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/MemMang/heap_2.c). Там как раз берётся глобальный статический массив, из которого потом берутся участки памяти.

Comment: Никто не даст начинающему реализовывать malloc.

Comment: "Есть догадка, чтобы реализовать free, нужно пройтись циклом и задать значение NULL. "
Нет. Память выделяется в куче. Вот и надо кусок памяти взять и назначать куски ее определенным указателям. А освобождать - назначать память свободной. Это можно сделать с помощью какой-то таблицы, где идентификаторам поставлены в соответствие длины и начальный адрес. Но это так сложно. Поэтому и не дают такое начинающим и даже среднему уровню

Comment: Всем спасибо, попробую и отпишусь!

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka. C первого сентября учат С. 6 занятий в месяц)

Comment: @Mike, это как раз не проблема для тех, кто прочитал про *sbrk()*. Или, как вы сказали, с помощью *mmap()*. Вот хороший ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479330/how-is-malloc-implemented-internally

Comment: А в сети искать не пробовали? Например, [тут](http://www.hardline.ru/selfteachers/Info/Programming/Teoria_OS/Glava%204/Index3.htm) вроде достаточно подробно рассказывают

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну смотрите.

Откуда брать память, вам заботиться не нужно: у вас память передаётся вашему алгоритму (см. пример, в котором она выделяется на стеке), так что вы просто работаете с переданной памятью.

Теперь, вам нужно организовать список блоков памяти. Для этого вам нужно написать структуру данных, описывающую блок памяти: его размер, положение, признак того, он занят или нет, и указатель на следующий блок. Где размещать этот список? Понятно, где: в вашей выделенной памяти! Внутри блока, кроме вот этой вот служебной информации, должна быть ещё и сама память (она у вас, понятно, будет по фиксированному смещению от начала блока).

Процедура инициализации сводится при этом к помещению в список одного большого блока памяти.

Более сложным является `malloc`: вам необходимо пройти по связному списку блоков (вначале в нём только один блок, но потом будет больше), найти первый подходящий по размеру, и откусить от него кусок нужного размера. При этом найденный блок разобьётся на два: выделенный кусок и остаток. Впрочем, остаток может быть настолько мал, что в него не поместится заголовок блока, и тогда вы отдадите целый кусок. Не забывайте, что вы отдаёте юзеру не указатель на весь блок памяти (зачем он ему?), а на начало памяти в нём.

`free` должно быть симметричным: вы получаете на вход указатель на кусок памяти, и помечаете его свободным. Не забудьте от указателя на память вашего блока перейти к указателю на сам блок. Если до него или после него находятся свободные блоки, их можно слить в один блок.

Код и структуры данных намеренно не даю, это ж учебное задание. Дерзайте, у вас хороший предмет и хороший преподаватель, вы многому научитесь!